# python3 urllib cant download url when umlauts "ä,ö,ü"

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, urllib

I have written a Python3 script which downloads a URL. However, it does not work if there is an "umlaut" in the URL (in this case "ü"). The URL does not work if I write "ue". How can I change to UTF 8?

```
import urllib.request

url = "https://www.corona-in-zahlen.de/landkreise/sk%20würzburg/"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "webpage.txt")
```

Comment: In the general case, this also depends on how the server encodes the URL; this begs the question how you obtained this URL in the first place, because any competent system would give you the URL in correctly encoded form (`sk%20w%c3%bcrzburg` if they use UTF-8 encoding, `sk%20w%fcrzburg` if they use legacy Latin-1, who knows what abominations if they are using PHP or Windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works if you replace the ü with a regular u:

```
import urllib.request

url = "https://www.corona-in-zahlen.de/landkreise/sk%20wurzburg/"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "webpage.txt")
```